# What's the meaning of "thin blood" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I don’t understand the meaning of this expression that I found in a novel I’m reading. A woman who lives in a hot country is speaking with a girl living in England. It’s summer, the girl is warm, the woman instead is cold. The girl is surprised, so the woman says:

> Maybe my blood has been thinned by the tropics

I found this expression only in a medical context. A thinned blood is a blood made thinner by an anticoagulant, but I don't think this is the meaning of the expression in this dialogue. Is it an idiom? Or a common way to say that her blood is accustomed to hot weather?

Comment: It's an old expression meaning to have become acclimatized to tropical weather. The blood doesn't really get thinner.

Comment: It's just something people say. [*Another use of the term 'thin blood' was/is used to describe someone who has just returned from the Tropics to colder climates. It's said the he/she feels the cold because hers/his blod is still 'thin'.
**As a pathologist of 40 or so years standing, with numerous medical publications behind me, I can only say that I have no idea at all what this type of 'thinning' means in haematological terms!***](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/12/messages/466.html#:~:text=Another%20use%20of%20the%20term,blod%20is%20still%20'thin'.)

Comment: A hotter liquid is less viscous aka runnier aka thinner. In bygone naive/folk biology/logic the person acclimatized to heat has thinner blood that is not appropriate for being in the cold so they'd be cold. Blood is thicker than water--it metaphorically sticks people together. Molasses in January.

Comment: FWIW living a high *altitude* does literally "thicken" the blood since your metabolism adjusts to create more oxygen-carrying red blood cells, but this is not the direct result of *temperature* changes (even though high altitudes often have colder temperatures).

Comment: @alephzero Interesting...while I do live in a tropical zone, I also live at a fairly high altitude. I have noticed that when blood samples are drawn, my blood seems thicker than from when I used to live close to sea level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Thin blooded" is a very old expression meaning "vulnerable to the cold."

This has, as you note, [no connection to blood thinners](https://www.reference.com/world-view/blood-thinners-make-cold-6a16205833b18f54)